# el.parentNode возвращает null в setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Есть система, отображающая уведомления на клиенте.

Уведомления приходят по websocket и показываются при вызове функции showNotification(), в которой они создаются путем добавления html-кода через innerHTML контейнера.

Для скрытия уведомления на кнопку в уведомлении вешается событие клик и в функцию hideNotification() передается сам элемент, в которой далее уведомление удаляется путем присваивания анимации скрытия через style, а далее, через 500мс, удаляется при помощи el.parentNode.removeChild(el).

```
function showNotification(thisNotification){
// action: "notification"
// hide: "auto"
// message: "This email is already in use"
// title: "An error occurred"
// type: "error"
let html = '';
switch(thisNotification.type){
    case 'error':{
        html+=`
        <div class="popup-notification popup-notification-error autohide">
            <h1 class="notification-title">${thisNotification.title}</h1>
            <span class="notification-description description-error">${thisNotification.message}</span>
        </div>`
        
        notification_container.innerHTML += html;
        let thisAutoHide_element = document.getElementsByClassName('autohide')[0];
        setTimeout(() => {
            hideNotification(thisAutoHide_element);
        }, 5000);
        break;
    }
    case 'friends':{
        html+=`
        <div class="popup-notification popup-notification-friend">
            <h1 class="notification-title">${thisNotification.title}</h1>
            <div class="buttons-container">
                <button class="notification-button button-confirm friend-request-accept">Accept</button>
                <button class="notification-button button-cancel friend-request-reject">Reject</button>
            </div>
        </div>`
        notification_container.innerHTML += html;
        const thisNotification_buttonAccept = notification_container.getElementsByClassName('friend-request-accept')[0];
        const thisNotification_buttonReject = notification_container.getElementsByClassName('friend-request-reject')[0];
        thisNotification_buttonAccept.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let from = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('notification-title')[0].getElementsByClassName('account-notification-link')[0].getAttribute('uid');
            let thisNote = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            hideNotification(thisNote);
            send_friendRequestResponse('accept', from);
        })
        thisNotification_buttonReject.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let from = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('notification-title')[0].getElementsByClassName('account-notification-link')[0].getAttribute('uid');
            send_friendRequestResponse('reject', from);
            let thisNote = document.getElementsByClassName('popup-notification-friend')[0];
            hideNotification(thisNote);
        })
        break;
    }
    case 'alert':{
        html+= `
        <div class="popup-notification popup-notification-alert">
            <h1 class="notification-title">${thisNotification.title}</h1>
            <span class="notification-description">${thisNotification.message}</span>
            <button class="notification-button button-ok alert-button-ok">OK</button>
        </div>
        `
        notification_container.innerHTML += html;
        const buttonOK = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-button-ok');
        for(let i = 0; i < buttonOK.length; i++){
            buttonOK[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                let thisNote = this.parentNode;
                console.log('thisNote = ', thisNote);
                hideNotification(thisNote);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
function hideNotification(el){
el.style.animationName = 'notification-hide';
setTimeout(() => {        
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}, 500);
```

}

Проблема заключается в том, что любые уведомления, кроме 'friends', удаляются, а при принятии заявки в друзья через уведомление 'friends' - выводится ошибка *TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')* для строки *el.parentNode.removeChild(el);*

Ошибка как-то связана с setTimeout, потому что до него parentNode находится:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]